# On average, how many steps does it take to first reach state $2$ from state $4$?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

> Consider the Markov chain with transition matrix,
> $$
> P=\pmatrix{ 
> 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
> \frac14 & 0 & \frac14 & \frac14  & \frac14\\
> 0 & \frac12 & 0 & \frac12 & 0 \\
> 0 & \frac12 & \frac12 & 0 &0\\
> 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &0
> }  
> $$
> On average, how many steps does it take to first reach state $2$ from state $4$? Hint: Consider $r_i(j)=\mathbb E_i[\inf\{n\geq0:X_n=j\}]$ and condition on the first step.

By tower law,

\begin{align}
r_i(j) &= \mathbb E\left[\mathbb E_i[\inf\{n\geq0:X_n=j\}|X_1\right] \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^5 \mathbb E_i[\inf\{n\geq0:X_n=j\}|X_1=k]P_{ik}
\end{align}

Now, I am stuck. How to proceed further? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Define $E(x)$ has the expected number of steps to reach state $2$ from state $x$. Clearly $E(2)=0$. Using states, we have the following equations
$$E(1)=E(2)+1=1$$
$$E(3)=\frac{1}{2}E(2)+\frac{1}{2}E(4)+1=\frac{1}{2}E(4)+1$$
$$E(4)=\frac{1}{2}E(2)+\frac{1}{2}E(3)+1=\frac{1}{2}E(3)+1$$
$$E(5)=E(2)+1=1$$

Adding $2$ times the $3^\text{rd}$ equation with the $2^\text{nd}$ equation gives
$$2E(4)=\frac{1}{2}E(4)+3$$
$$E(4)=\boxed{2}$$

Comment: Could you describe how you formulate those equations? @AlanAbraham Like Why $\mathbb E(1)=\mathbb E(2)+1,\mathbb E(3)=\frac12\mathbb E(2)+\frac12\mathbb E(4)+1?$

Comment: @falamiw It's kind of like a recursion. For example, let's say you are state $3$ and take a step. From the markov chain matrix, we can see that you have a $\frac{1}{2}$ probability to go to state $2$ and a $\frac{1}{2}$ probability to go to state $4$. Let's say we go to state $2$, then the expected number of steps to get to $2$ from $3$ when we went on this path will be $E(2)+1$. Similarly, if we instead went to state $4$, then the expected number of steps to get to $2$ from $3$ following this path would be $E(4)+1$.

Comment: We can then use the formula for expected value to say that $E(3)=\frac{1}{2}(E(2)+1)+\frac{1}{2}(E(4)+1)=\frac{1}{2}E(2)+\frac{1}{2}E(4)+1$.

Comment: OK, I understand but why we need to add plus $1$? What's the meaning of that? @AlanAbraham

Comment: @falamiw that represents that you took $1$ step from $3$ to get to your next state.